# Subclassing Generics

Tags: swift, syntax

Xcode 9 has a new warning which lights up for the following issue. The warning is

> redundant superclass constraint

```
class TypeA<T: NSManagedObject> {}

class TypeB<L: NSManagedObject, U: TypeA<L>> {}

class TypeC<Event> {}
```

Given that Event is a subclass of NSManagedObject, in what way can I suppress the above warning?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find more information in the full compiler output in the Report navigator:

```
main.swift:7:16: warning: redundant superclass constraint 'L' : warning: redundant superclass constraint 'L' : 'NSManagedObject'
class TypeB<L: NSManagedObject, U: TypeA<L>> {}
               ^
main.swift:7:36: note: superclass constraint 'L' : 'NSManagedObject' inferred from type here
class TypeB<L: NSManagedObject, U: TypeA<L>> {}
                                   ^
```

Which means that in

```
class TypeB<L: NSManagedObject, U: TypeA<L>> {}
```

the restriction `L: NSManagedObject` is implicitly given in `TypeA<L>`,
which already restricts `L` to be a subclass of `NSManagedObject`.

You can remove that constraint from the `classB` declaration:

```
class TypeB<L, U: TypeA<L>> {}
```

Comment: Thank you @Martin. I will accept your answer as correct.